# T-SQL - Continue Query Execution on Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

How to continue Query Execution if any error occurs? If in the following example 2nd query fails then rest queries didn't execute.

```
INSERT Schema1.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
INSERT Schema2.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
INSERT Schema3.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
INSERT Schema4.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: put every insert into a try catch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you don't want to log anything you can just separate the queries by using GO

```
INSERT Schema1.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
GO
INSERT Schema2.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
GO
INSERT Schema3.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
GO
INSERT Schema4.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
GO
```

Comment: Exactly. I don't want to Log anything. I will try this.

Comment: Resulting in 3 unhandled errors.
Even if you don't want to log anything, try..catch will catch the errors so, albeit loosely, they are handled.

Comment: He/she just wanted to continue the query, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each statement in a try..catch block.

That way you could log failures and no exactly waht didn't execute as expected.

See link below for try catch syntax.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
begin try 
    INSERT Schema1.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
end try
begin catch
     -- what you want to do in catch
end catch    

begin try 
    INSERT Schema2.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
end try
begin catch
      -- what you want to do in catch
end catch    

and so on...
```

Comment: If i remove the catch statements & keep only try, Will it work?

Comment: no. If you start a try you have to and it with catch. The catch may be empty offcourse

Answer (score 0):

```
   -- maybe like this :)
    -- using tran catch

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN
     INSERT Schema1.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) 
     VALUES (5,   N'Transaction', 2)
     INSERT Schema2.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role])
    VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
    INSERT Schema3.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) 
    VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
   INSERT Schema4.[Menu] ([CompanyId], [Menu], [Role]) 
   VALUES (5, N'Transaction', 2)
   COMMIT TRAN
  END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
   ROLLBACK TRAN
  END CATCH
```

Comment: this will undo the succeeded inserts if just one fails. I dont see the differences with the OP original code

Comment: your originals code if fails one, others can execute if not fails. 
and my code if only one fails or more, all is fails too...

Comment: your code will result in all inserts rollbacked if one or more fails. That is exact what the OP does NOT wants